# Word to InDesign: Import leaves blank text boxes with overset text mark

Tags: adobe-indesign, import, microsoft-word

After I import my Word Document into InDesign it only places the first few pages. Afterwords I get empty pages, eventhough the word documents is shown in the story editor. How can I force InDesign to import all of the text?

[image: screenshot of my Indesign file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to remove the pictures from the import. That did the trick.

Comment: Presumably the first image were too big to fit inside the text frame, so it became overset text – then everything after that will be overset text. But in general, you should always remove all images from Word before importing. Word tends to turn images into some ghastly lossy format that’s a fraction of the original image’s quality and quite useless for printing. Linking the image file directly in InDesign is the way to go.

Comment: Remember to *accept* your own answer.